# sending bool value from uiwebview to source code

Tags: javascript, iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiwebview

I have 3 files, appdelegate.h, appdelegate.m, and mainwindow.xib

I have a uiwebview set up to load my site within those three files. I have a link in my site that triggers a JS function that changes the window location to /test/

Now, I want that link to trigger a function in the app, so I have this code:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView
shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    if ( [request.mainDocumentURL.relativePath
          isEqualToString:@"/test"] ) {
        NSLog( @"test" );
        return false;
    }


    return true;
}
```

it is currently in the appdelegate.m file. Nothing happens when I change the location to /test. What to do?

Comment: C++? The language used for Cocoa Touch development is Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you set the delegate of the UIWebView to your app delegate